# Ball rotating in a Turntable

Tags: animation, physics, simulation

I made a turntable to make some experiments and make some studies about Coriolis and Euler forces acting in different frames of reference.

```
    Manipulate[Module[{max, 
   eqs = {(t vx0 + x0) Cos[t/2] + t (vy0 + x0/2) Sin[t/2], 
     t (vy0 + x0/2) Cos[t/2] - (t vx0 + x0) Sin[t/2]}},
  max = (If[NumberQ[#1], #1, 40] &)[
    Quiet@FindRoot[Evaluate[Plus @@ (eqs^2) == 1], {t, 155, 0, 5000}, 
       MaxIterations -> 50][[1, 2]]];
  If[max == 0, max = .01];
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[eqs], {t, 0, max}, 
   Prolog -> {GrayLevel[.8], Disk[{0, 0}, 1], PointSize[.02], 
     GrayLevel[.0], Point[{0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 1000]], {{x0, .5, 
   "initial position x"}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{vx0, -.0004, 
   "initial velocity in x"}, -0.1, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{vy0, .23, 
   "initial velocity in y"}, -.24, .24, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

What i want to do is to make this simulation 3D. 
As the picture below shows

[image]

Comment: I think the question is too open-ended because it's not made clear how realistic the 3D scene should be. E.g., to simulate the correct rolling motion of a sphere would be more challenging than to use a dot... the desired level of detail should be clarified first. I assume you don't want to account for the moment of inertia of the sphere, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{ 
   eqs = {(t vx0 + x0) Cos[t/2] + t (vy0 + x0/2) Sin[t/2], 
     t (vy0 + x0/2) Cos[t/2] - (t vx0 + x0) Sin[t/2]}}, 
  max = (If[NumberQ[#1], #1, 40] &)[
    Quiet@FindRoot[Evaluate[Plus @@ (eqs^2) == 1], {t, 155, 0, 5000}, 
       MaxIterations -> 50][[1, 2]]];
  If[max == 0, max = .01];

  Show[ParametricPlot3D[Append[eqs, 0.05], {t, 0, max}, PlotPoints -> 1000], 
   Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.01}}, 1], 
   Sphere[Append[eqs /. t -> tt, 0.05], 0.04]}], PlotRange -> All, 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
  ], 
 {tt, 0, max, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 {{x0, .5, "initial position x"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vx0, -.0004, "initial velocity in x"}, -0.1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vy0, .23, "initial velocity in y"}, -.24, .24, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: When running you code i get the followuing error: **An unrecognized option name ("PlotPoints") was encountered while reading a Graphics.** (under v.10.0)

Comment: Done. In this case it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, i had the same problem with PlotPoints. After deleting it runs!! Tks!

Comment: Is it possible to change the "point" for a Ball? or Sphere?

Comment: @dcvilela Sure, see the edit.

Comment: @thedude That´s it! Seems similiar to the real example.

Comment: The animation would be more effective if it somehow showed the turntable disk rotating -- say with a single (or a couple) radii that turn with the turntable.

Comment: @murray I think so. It would be more similar to the real situation. Because the move equations have friction interaction (ball-disk).

Comment: I could solve the whole problem for you, accounting for friction/slipping, the energy required to rotate the ball, the centripetal forces etc. I only visualized the code you provided, and I don't think rotating the disk will add any more realism unless you state how changing the rotation speed will affect the trajectory explicitly.